# Geometric vs Binomial Distribution in Russian Roulette

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Can someone clarify where I went wrong and clear my confusions?

A man is playing a Russian roulette game by himself with 1 bullet and 6 chambers. He will only play for 8 rounds. What is the probability the gun fires on the 9th try? I believe this is a geometric series, with $p = 1/6$ and the 9th trial being the first success $p(X=9)$. However, when asked to find the probability of the man surviving this game, we also need to account for the gun firing on the 9th, 10th ... all the way to infinity. So, we want to find $p(X\ge 9)$. But then this starts to look like a binomial. Is this geometric or binomial and why? If it indeed is a binomial, what makes it NOT a geometric distribution?

However, if this is a geometric distribution, the memoryless property holds which means if given that the gun did not fire for the last 7 rounds, the probability it fires on the 8th round should be the same as it firing on the 1st. But clearly when plugging the numbers into the geometric pmf, the probabilities are different. I am so confused.

Answer (score 1):

> However, when asked to find the probability of the man surviving this game, we also need to account for the gun firing on the 9th, 10th ... all the way to infinity.

Let $~q = (1-p).$

Alternative approach is to simply find the probability that the gun did not fire in the first 8 tries, which is $~q^8.$

---

Following through on the original poster's approach, the probability that the gun fires for the first time on try $~k~$ where $~k \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 9}},~$ is

$$q^{k-1}p.$$

Then, you would want

$$\sum_{k=9}^\infty q^{k-1}p \\
= q^8 \times p \times (1 + q + q^2 + q^3 + \cdots) \\
=q^8 \times p \times \frac{1}{1-q} = q^8 \times p \times \frac{1}{p} = q^8.$$

Comment: Gracias for the elegant solution. A question: Am I to understand that the probability of not getting shot for 56 times = the probability of not getting shot 8 times? Or is the probability of surviving forever = the probability of surviving the first 8 trigger pulls?

Answer (score 0):

- This is indeed a geometric distribution. You don't explain why you think it is binomial, but we might be able to help you understand if you explain your thought process more.
- You misunderstand the memoryless property. The probability it fires in the 8th round is $(1-p)^7 p$ as given by the PMF, which is indeed different from the probability of firing in the first round, $p$. But the memorylessness property is about the probability it fires in the 8th round **conditioned on the event that the gun did not fire the first 7 rounds**. This is still $p$:
  $$P(X=8 \mid X > 7) = \frac{P(X=8)}{P(X > 7)} = \frac{(1-p)^7 p}{(1-p)^7} = p = P(X=1).$$